# How can I create template for specific page in module?

Tags: 7, theming

I am completely new to drupal, and just started learning.

Here's my issue:

I have created a module, called 'doom'. It has only one form.

I would like to remove all the default elements ( header, footer, sidebar ) and to add custom  elements.

I tried this,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function doom_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'doom');
    $template_file_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $module_path);
    foreach ($template_file_objects as $key => $template_file_object) {
        if (!isset($theme_registry[$key]['theme path']) || !preg_match('#/themes/#', $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'])) {
            $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'] = $module_path;
            $theme_registry[$key] = array_merge($theme_registry[$key], $template_file_object);
            $theme_registry[$key]['type'] = 'module';
        }
    }
}
```

This code changes all the pages in the site. But I just wanted to customize the template for 'doom' page.  http://example.com/drupal/doom

Comment: Have a look at [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656), there's a section about page template. Scroll down or search for "page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php".

Comment: Means you want to create custom template file to display your changes on that particular page only. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function doom_menu() {
  $items['doom'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'doom_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function doom_theme() {
  // Get the path to this module and define theme dir.
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'doom');
  $theme_dir   = $module_path . '/theme';

  // Themable elements. This will look for "sample-template.tpl.php" file
  // in the "YOUR_MODULE_DIR/theme" folder. That file can be anything.
  return array(
    'sample-template' => array(
      'template' => 'sample-template',
      'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
      'path' => $theme_dir,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Menu callback.
 */
function doom_page_callback() {
  // Get your template and display ONLY the contents of that file.
  print theme('sample-template', array('content' => t('Optionally, pass dynamic content here.')));
}
```

And the `sample-template.tpl.php` file:

```
<div id="sample-template">
  <?php print $content; ?>
</div>
```

This should give you the idea. If you still want to theme the HTML header/footer from the front end theme, you should be able to create `page--doom.tpl.php` file there and customize what is displayed. In that case, just return the output instead of printing it in `doom_page_callback()`.

Hope this helps.